# Variance and Covariance of Fixed Effects expressed in Quadratic Form

Tags: variance, linear-model, covariance, linear-algebra, quadratic-form

I know that for a simple vector $x$ of length $n$, the variance of this vector $\sigma_x^2= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{2}-\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right)^{2}$ can be written as $x^{\top} A x$, where $A= \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{I}_{n \times n}-\frac{1}{n^2} \mathbf{1}_{n \times n}$. I get this quadratic form by trying some simple case and then thinking about the general way of the representation. I don't know if there is some general rules to construct $A$. And thus I get problem when constructing similar representation on the variance and covariance of fixed effects in a linear model. I rephrase the linear model below, which is originally from a paper I am reading.

"""

Consider a data set composed of observations on $N$ groups with $T_{g}$ observations in the $g$ th group. The "analysis of covariance" model posits that outcomes can be written $$y_{g t}=\alpha_{g}+x_{g t}^{\prime} \delta+\varepsilon_{g t} \quad\left(g=1, \ldots, N, t=1, \ldots, T_{g} \geq 2\right)$$, where $\alpha_{g}$ is a group effect and $x_{g t}$ is a vector of strictly exogenous covariates.

The variability in outcomes attributable to $\alpha_g$ can be written $\sigma_{\alpha}^{2}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{g=1}^{N} T_{g}\left(\alpha_{g}-\bar{\alpha}\right)^{2}$ where $\bar{\alpha}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{g=1}^{N} T_{g} \alpha_{g}$.

This model can be aligned with the notation of $y_{i}=x_{i}^{\prime} \beta+\varepsilon_{i} \quad(i=1, \ldots, n)$ by letting $i=$ $i(g, t)$, where $i(\cdot, \cdot)$ is bijective, with inverse denoted $(g(\cdot), t(\cdot))$, and defining $y_{i}=y_{g t}$, $\varepsilon_{i}=\varepsilon_{g t}$ $x_{i}=\left(d_{i}^{\prime}, x_{g t}^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}, \quad \beta=\left(\alpha^{\prime}, \delta^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}, \quad \alpha=\left(\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{N}\right)^{\prime} \quad \text { and } \quad d_{i}=\left(\mathbf{1}_{\{g=1\}}, \ldots, \mathbf{1}_{\{g=N\}}\right)^{\prime}$

To represent the target parameter in this notation, we write $\sigma_{\alpha}^{2}=\beta^{\prime} A \beta$, where $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A_{d}^{\prime} A_{d} & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right] \quad \text { for } A_{d}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(d_{1}-\bar{d}, \ldots, d_{n}-\bar{d}\right) \text { and } \bar{d}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{i}$.

"""

I am confused about how and why the $A$ should be written as this. The $A_d$ seems to be a $N \times n$ matrix, and thus $A_{d}^{\prime} A_{d}$ would be a $n \times n$ matrix, and I cannot see why $\sigma_{\alpha}^{2}=\beta^{\prime} A \beta$. It would make more sense if it is $A_{d} A_{d}^{\prime}$ and I try some calculation using the software and find using $A_{d} A_{d}^{\prime}$ get the right answer. However I still struggle to show $\beta^{\prime} A \beta$ equivalent to $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{g=1}^{N} T_{g}\left(\alpha_{g}-\bar{\alpha}\right)^{2}$. (Actually I find I can construct a $A$ directly by using $\mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{1}$ just like the simple vector case but I don't know how to connect this $A$ with the $A_{d}$)

And also I want to estimate the variability in outcomes attributable to the covariance $\sigma_{\alpha, X}$ between $\alpha_g$ and $x_{g t}^{\prime} \delta$. I think this can be done by constructing a new $A$, and I guess it would be something like  $A= \frac{1}{2} \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & A_{x}^{\prime} A_{d} \\ A_{d}^{\prime} A_{x} & 0\end{array}\right]$ where $A_{x}$ is constructed similarly to $A_{d}$. But I am not sure if this is correct and what is the general way to construct $A$ in all potential cases.